# Should I allow kernel updates?

Tags: 12.04, updates, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and the update manager appears daily with updates. I am ok with other updates but I want to know about Linux Kernel updates: Should I update to new versions, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install any kernel you want. There is no problem on using one or multiple Kernels at a time. But sometime you should consider the Kernel Mapping to your Ubuntu Version. For example following link lists out the mapping of different kernel to different version of OS:

[Ubuntu to Mainline kernel version mapping](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/info/kernel-version-map.html)

You can get a complete information of Kernel installing/removing from following link.

[Kernel Mainline Builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

It helped me a lot to install a new kernel in Ubuntu 12.04.2. Now I can chose any kernel 3.5.0 or 3.8.0 from grub menu.

Following link illustrates how Ubuntu 12.04 LTS works actually. It illustates in very nice way, you would also like:

[Ubuntu LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=How+to+upgrade+to+ubuntu+12.04.3&titlesearch=Titles)

Hope this short description helps you.

Comment: this is no short description :)

Comment: @mojo706: ha ha ha.. You are right! I was talking about my short answer.. ;) Although to get such information, you have to read a lot of information.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel manages the hardware of every Linux system and makes it available to the various processes.

Updating to a new Kernel keeps you up-to-date with Security Patches, Stability Improvements, Updated Drivers, and New Kernel Functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want something specifically from a newer Kernel, probably don't need to update. 99% of the time auto update is all you really need (unless you are fixing a particular problem).